# How can I send model errors through RedirectToAction()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some action for example

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(Model login)
{
  .....
  //Login fail
  ModelState.AddModelError("loginError","Login fail");

  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //here i need send model
    return RedirectToAction("SomeAction2","Controller");
  }

  return View(login);
}
```

`SomeAction2` is not as same type `Model` as `SomeAction`. But `SomeAction2` has a partial view that have same type with view `SameAction`.  Can anyone tell me how I can send a model error to this partial view?

Comment: Guess you should use TempData for passing information and then in the target Action readd to ModelState each error. I think it's better to do some refactor and simply return a different View. But not knowing the scenario I cannot be 100% sure

Comment: Why are you Redirecting? and why are you redirecting across controllers? (Just curious).

Comment: Maybe he wants to redirect so he can follow the PRG pattern.

Comment: I have page where i have shopping cart and if user didn't logged i show Login form. And when user submit form but login was fail i need show this login form with data that user entered and show ModelError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have to use 
`return View("ViewName");`

Then you can use a ViewBag collection to add the error messages.

Comment: I can't return View("SomeAction2") because in SomeAction2 perform some procedure and then i show View.

Comment: So add the procedure in the SomeAction. You can always encapsulate the method